# How to remove active OEM (EFI System) partition from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I recently bought a new Asus laptop with Windows 8 on it. After a week of hating it, I did a clean install of Windows 7 on the machine. I had to disable SecureBoot in the BIOS to even be able install Windows 7 from disk. Anyway, the installation went fine, and I'm running Windows 7.

In Computer Management in Windows 7 I found an old OEM (EFI System) partition which I would like to remove. But I want to do this without formatting the entire drive, as Windows is now working really well.

This is my current setup of partitions. I want to merge that first nameless partition with G: if at all possible. Computer Management doesn't allow me to do anything with that locked partition.

[image]

I tried to remove it with DiskPart.exe [With this tutorial](http://noaveragegeek.com/deleting-the-windows-7-oem-partition)

But it told me I could not remove system directories.

Is there anyway I can keep Windows 7 working, but remove that annoying locked partition?

Comment: ok, ill ask there. thx

Comment: I think that these partition is required for EFI systems to boot, so it is not a good idea to remove it. Moreover, it's only 300 MB on a 1 TB hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DO NOT REMOVE THE EFI SYSTEM PARTITION (ESP) FROM AN EFI-BOOTING COMPUTER!*** That partition is *required* to boot the computer, so removing it would result in an unbootable computer! If the computer were booting in BIOS mode, it would be safe to remove -- but because Windows ties its partition table type to its boot mode, it seems quite unlikely that you'd have an ESP on a BIOS-booting computer.